# I am creating a layout with 3 frame layouts each one have one fragment and i need to dynamical add them in first fragment there is image slid show

Tags: android

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class framelayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    View imagelayout,itemlayout,recycle_layout;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.frame_layout);
            FrameLayout frm1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame2);
            FrameLayout frm2=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame3);
            FrameLayout frm3=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame4);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            imagelayout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout,null);
            itemlayout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlayout,null);
            recycle_layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycle_layout,null);
            frm1.addView(imagelayout);
            frm2.addView(itemlayout);
            frm3.addView(recycle_layout);

            images_activity img=new images_activity();
            img.findViewById(R.id.frame2);



        }

    }
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class images_activity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.imagelayout);
            CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

            ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);


        }


    }

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    int[] mResources = {R.drawable.first,R.drawable.second,R.drawable.third,R.drawable.forth};
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.images_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

This is my full code i merge code in one file to post.i need in one frame layout have image slideshow.i have check my code it is work fine but when it is come to add to frame layout it is not working if any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you make your Fragment transaction? You need to have something like this:

```
 FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame1,fragmentOne);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: can you suggest me any example project which is suitable to my project

Comment: Hi MikeB can you help me to improve my layout.as i post in my problem i have image slideshow in frame2.frame2 is placed in frame1.frame1 has text view.text is a recycle view when we change the text image slideshow is also need to change.Like if we have mobile as text images slideshow need to be mobile pics,when we change it to another item like camera slideshow will have camera pics.it is my project can you suggest me any example. or sample code which is suitable to my case.